# ASP.Net CollapsiblePanelextender Control

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-controls, collapsiblepanelextender

Afternoon All,

I am wonding if i can configure and use a collapsiblePanelextender in ASP.net within a table.  I would likt this to be used for a minutes of meeting system that i am creating. I have the following code and thought that if i added pnlPresenter and pnlTime to the CollapseControlID along with pnlHeader i would be able to get this to work but i cant.

Has anyone got any other suggestions?

```
 <table width="100%">
    <tr>
           <td class="style3">Topic</td>
            <td class="style2">Presenter</td>
            <td>Time Alloted</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
           <td class="style1" colspan="3">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeader" runat="server" CssClass="cpHeader" Width="228%" Height="18px">
                1.   Agenda Item 1
            <asp:Image ID="ImgToggle" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/collapse.jpg" ImageAlign="Middle" />
            </asp:Panel>
            </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td class="style3">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody" >
                The Agenda topic details goes within here, The Agenda topic details goes within here, 
                The Agenda topic details goes within here, The Agenda topic details goes within here,.
            </asp:Panel>
            </td> 
            <td class="style2"> 
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPresenter" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody" Width="107px">
                Presenters Name
            </asp:Panel>
            </td>
            <td class="style2"> 
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlTime" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody" Width="107px">
                Time
            </asp:Panel>
            </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Many Thanks in advance

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not *entirely* clear what you want to achieve here, especially as there's no CollapsiblePanelExtender in the markup you've posted, so I'm writing this on the assumption that you want to display a page for a meeting where each agenda item is expandable/collapsible.

I suggest you build your table using a Repeater instead of hard-coding it into your page, then for each agenda item the Repeater can render a new row for you. Inside the row that's rendered by the Repeater, you can then have the agenda topic as a header, and the agenda item details as a panel that's expanded/collapsed using the extender:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="AgendaRepeater" DataSourceID="AgendaDataSource">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="AgendaTopicLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Topic") %>' />
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="PanelExpandContractImageButton" ImageUrl="~/images/zoom_in_16x16.gif" />
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="AgendaItemDetailsPanel" Height="0px">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TopicDetailsLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>' /><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PresenterLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Presenter") %>' /><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TimeLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Time") %>' />
                </asp:Panel>
                <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="AgendaItemDetailsPanel"
                        Collapsed="true" ExpandControlID="PanelExpandContractImageButton" CollapseControlID="PanelExpandContractImageButton"
                        ImageControlID="PanelExpandContractImageButton" CollapsedImage="~/images/zoom_in_16x16.gif"
                        ExpandedImage="~/images/zoom_out_16x16.gif" ExpandedSize="100" ExpandDirection="Vertical"
                        ScrollContents="true" />
           </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Many thanks.  I have used a repeater as you have suggested and this works a treat.